# How to hide ApplicationIBarIcons on pivot's selectionchange

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have a Pivot and 5 Pivot items inside it, by an xml I am adding and removing those pivot items as per the need but  the thing is I want some of my ApplicationBarIcons visible on selection of certain pivotitems and collapse on certain pivotitems view,I cannot do this by the help of checking selectedindex because dynamically they are getting changed. How can I do it?

Comment: you can manage it via tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you are handling the loading of the app bar. Are you doing in the the `XAML` code or C#?

If you are doing it in C#, there should be a `Visible` property for the `ApplicationBar` object.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to check out the Cimbalino toolkit for windows phone! It has a bindable application appbar, so you can tweak the IsVisible property when you switch through the pivots! > There is a SelectionChanged event on the Pivot to track what pivot is currently active, I would check the Name of the pivot or a Tag like Techloverr suggests

Example cimbalino http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/cimbalino-windows-phone-4de77988

Answer (score 1):

You can create ApplicationBar for certain pivot items of pivot page like this using id.If id =0,it will take automatically pivot Page(Item) 0 .By using this,you can choose which all AppBars has to be in whole pivot pages and in selective pivot pages(Items).

```
<phone:Pivot>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
            <appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>
                <appBarUtils:SelectionMapping SourceIndex="0" TargetIndex="0"/>
            </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger.SelectionMappings>

            <appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="0"   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="2" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.home.png" Text="home" Command="{Binding HomeNavigationCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.money.png" Text="collection" Command="{Binding CollectionPageCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}"/>
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

                <appBarUtils:AppBar Id="3"  BackgroundColor="{StaticResource AppBarBg}" ForegroundColor="{StaticResource Foreground}">
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton x:Name="ConfirmationAppBarButton" IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.cancel.rest.png" Text="cancel" Command="{Binding OrderCancelButtonCommand}"/>
                    <appBarUtils:AppBarButton IconUri="/Assets\Images\appbar.check.rest.png" Text="ok" Command="{Binding OrderConfirmationButtonCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding Model.EnableCheck,Mode=TwoWay}" />
                </appBarUtils:AppBar>

            </appBarUtils:SwitchAppBarAction>
        </appBarUtils:SelectedPivotItemChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</phone:Pivot>
```

//Assuming your views are in View Folder

Use AppBarUtils from [here](http://appbarutils.codeplex.com/) and refer in code.
You can have different appbars for each pivot item using the above sample code.Hope this will help you.